# Consecutive Draws from Urn

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, polya-urn-model

An urn contains 4 black balls and 6 white balls. What is the probability of getting 1 black ball and 1 white ball in two consecutive draws from the urn?

I know this is supposed to be easy. So i tried

(4/10) * (6/9) = 0.26667

But the correct answer is 0.53... which is *2 of that. Any hint why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the order doesn't matter: you could also draw the white ball first, then the black ball:
$$
\frac{4}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9} + \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{4}{9} = \frac{8}{15}
$$
If you know a little bit of combinatorics, we could also solve this problem by counting via combinations:
$$
\frac{\binom{4}{1} \binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{8}{15}
$$